# Db connection not released from connection pool

Tags: connection-pooling, windows-server-2012

I am migrating an existing site from Win2003/.Net 4.0 to Win2012 as lift and shift (no change in code).
The problem is that the connections are not released from the connection pool and errors after reaching 100 very quickly. When I checked the SQL Server(also 2012) using sp_who2, I can see the connections sleeping and not getting released.

This code properly closes connections and uses Enterprise library Data blocks and works fine in the old environment. Any clues on where the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

After much research, I found out that the issue was in a section of the code where data readers were not being disposed off correctly in certain scenarios.

What is still not clear is why it works without the connection leaking in Win2003/iis6 combination. What was ruled out is any external factors that would contribute such a behavior in 2012 Server environment.